# SQL update query issue

Tags: sql, sql-update

I just accidentally noticed that a Query like

```
Update tableA tableA set id = '5'
```

Works fine. Should this give error as I am using table name twice here.
Any thoughts why is this working fine ?

Comment: thanks for pointing out edited the question. It was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second `tableA` is seen as an alias. There is no constraint in regards to the name of the alias, so you can have the same name on the alias as the table name.

Comment: Ahh.. how stupid of me .. Should have guessed that  :\

Comment: @Andy897 Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

your code exactly equal

```
Update tableA as 'tableA' set id = "5"
```

or

```
Update tableA as "tableA" set id = "5"
```

this is simple alias as [Sql Alias Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: You have the quotes the wrong way. In (standard) SQL identifiers are quoted with double quotes and string literals are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: ooooh so sorry I am coming from mysql area so that's allowed in our area butI will add it as "or"